# Create a label for each input of type text using input attribute (id, name)

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).name != '') {
      var label = $("<label >").attr('style', "display:none !important;").attr('for', $("input").attr("id")).text($("input").attr("name"));
      $('input').append(label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Account Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="account_reference_textbox" id="account_reference_textbox" maxlength="35" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Forename</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name_textbox" id="first_name_textbox" maxlength="10" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Customer Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="customer_reference_textbox" id="customer_reference_textbox" maxlength="25" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name_textbox" id="last_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Company Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="company_name_textbox" id="company_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    <html>
```

I am trying to create label for each input of type text using its attribute name & Id using Jquery.

I have successfully created a label by using input attributes but failed to get its correct position.

Comment: If you're trying to get the name attribute of the `input`, you should use `$(this).attr('name')`. `$(this).name` will always return `undefined` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using   `$('input')` to append so all `label` are append in first input so use `$(this)` to append `label` in its correct position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).name != '') {
      var label = $("<label >").attr('style', "display:none !important;").attr('for', $("input").attr("id")).text($("input").attr("name"));
      $(this).parent().append(label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Account Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="account_reference_textbox" id="account_reference_textbox" maxlength="35" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Forename</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name_textbox" id="first_name_textbox" maxlength="10" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Customer Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="customer_reference_textbox" id="customer_reference_textbox" maxlength="25" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name_textbox" id="last_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Company Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="company_name_textbox" id="company_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Thank you guys !

In my example append(`$(this).append(label);`) cause some issue,it will append inside input.therefore not recognized by browser.
<input><label..></input>.It should be in below format

`<label style="display:none !important;" for="account_reference_textbox">account_reference_textbox</label>
<input name="account_reference_textbox" id="account_reference_textbox" maxlength="35" value="" type="text">`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want the labels to be placed, but this example will place them after each input:

also note that if you use  `$("input").attr("id")` rather than `$(this).attr("id")` then you get the id of the first `input`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).name != '') {
      var label = $("<label >").attr('style', "display:none !important;").attr('for', $(this).attr("id")).text($(this).attr("name"));
      $(this).after(label);
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).name != '') {
      var label = $("<label >").attr('style', "display:none !important;").attr('for', $(this).attr("id")).text($(this).attr("name"));
      $(this).after(label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Account Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="account_reference_textbox" id="account_reference_textbox" maxlength="35" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Forename</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name_textbox" id="first_name_textbox" maxlength="10" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Customer Reference</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="customer_reference_textbox" id="customer_reference_textbox" maxlength="25" value="">
            </td>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name_textbox" id="last_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Company Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="company_name_textbox" id="company_name_textbox" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it.